# Простая сортировка пузырьком в Java.Почему в результате сортировки выводятся промежуточные массивы вместе с результатом?

Tags: java, сортировка, вектор

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isSort = false;
        int temp = 0;
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input n:");
        int n = sn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input array:");
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sn.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
        while (!isSort) {
            isSort = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = temp;
                    isSort = false;
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш цикл `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++)` находится внутри цикла `while (!isSort) {`, а значит он будет постоянно выводить содержимое массива до тех пор, пока массив не отсортируется

Answer (score 1):

Когда просишь у пользователя ввести данные лучше использовать print или printf, чтобы не было такого "Введите данные: ", а курсор на другой строке. В твоем коде поправил эстетическую составляющую и исправил ошибку. Теперь у тебя выводится массив до сортировки и после. "Enter array: " элементы массива можно вводить через пробел, необязательно использовать enter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isSort = false;
        int temp = 0;
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter power array: ");
        int n = sn.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter array: ");
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sn.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Before sorting: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        while (!isSort) {
            isSort = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = temp;
                    isSort = false;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("After sorting: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, поняла)